# How to use concurrentHashMap in executorCompletionService?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I  search the database many times,even I have cache some result, it still cost took a long time.

```
List<Map<Long, Node>> aNodeMapList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> cacheRingMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (Ring startRing : startRings) {
    for (Ring endRing : endRings) {
        Map<String, Object> nodeMapResult = getNodeMapResult(startRing, endRing, cacheRingMap);
        Map<Long, Node> nodeMap = (Map<Long, Node>) nodeMapResult.get("nodeMap");
        if (nodeMap.size() > 0) {
            aNodeMapList.add(nodeMap);
        }
    }
}
```

getNodeMapResult is a function to search database according to `startRing`, `endRing`, and cache in `cacheRingMap`, and next time it may not need to search database if I find the result have exist in 
`cacheRingMap`.

My leader tell me that multithread  technology can be used. So I change it to executorCompletionService, but now I have a question, is this thread safe when I use concurrentHashMap to cache result in executorCompletionService?
 Will it run fast after I change?

```
int totalThreadCount = startRings.size() * endRings.size();
ExecutorService threadPool2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalThreadCount > 4 ? 4 : 2);
CompletionService<Map<String, Object>> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Map<String, Object>>(threadPool2);
for (Ring startRing : startRings) {
    for (Ring endRing : endRings) {
        completionService.submit(new Callable<Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> call() throws Exception {
                return getNodeMapResult(startRing, endRing, cacheRingMap);
            }
        });
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < totalThreadCount; i++) {
    Map<String, Object> nodeMapResult = completionService.take().get();
    Map<Long, Node> nodeMap = (Map<Long, Node>) nodeMapResult.get("nodeMap");
    if (nodeMap.size() > 0) {
        aNodeMapList.add(nodeMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this thread safe when I use concurrentHashMap to cache result in executorCompletionService?

The `ConcurrentHashMap` itself is thread safe, as its name suggests ("Concurrent"). However, that doesn't mean that the code that uses it is thread safe.

For instance, if your code  does the following:

```
SomeObject object = cacheRingMap.get(someKey); //get from cache
if (object == null){ //oh-oh, cache miss
    object = getObjectFromDb(someKey); //get from the db
    cacheRingMap.put(someKey, object); //put in cache for next time
}
```

Since the `get` and `put` aren't performed atomically in this example, two threads executing this code could end up both looking for the same key first in the cache, and then in the db. It's still thread-safe, but we performed two db lookups instead of just one. But this is just a simple example, more complex caching logic (say one that includes cache invalidation and removals from the cache map) can end up being not just wasteful, but actually incorrect. It all depends on how the map is used and what guarantees you need from it. I suggest you read the [ConcurrentHashMap javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). See what it can guarantee, and what it cannot.

> Will it run fast after I change？

That depends on too many parameters to know in advance. How would the database handle the concurrent queries? How many queries are there? How fast is a single query? Etc. The best way of knowing is to actually try it out.

As a side note, if you're looking for ways to improve performance, you might want to try using a batch query. The flow would then be to search the cache for all the keys you need, gather the keys you need to look up, and then send them all together in a single query to the database. In many cases, a single large query would run faster that a bunch of smaller ones.

Also, you should check whether concurrent lookups in the map are faster than single threaded ones in your case. Perhaps parallelizing only the query itself, and not the cache lookup could yield better results in your case.

Comment: When two threads execute put method to cacheRingMap , is it still thread-safe?I have not add synchronized key word

Comment: Read the `ConcurrentHashMap` documentation. It's thread safe.